# Estava tentando tirar o title_bar e a aplicação não corre!

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ruimiguel.pap">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei apenas: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` & `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Comment: Seria melhor apresentar o código em forma textual para melhor analise.

Comment: Não coloque aqui nos comentários, clique em EDITAR  e adicione o xml por completo na pergunta.

Comment: Ja está! Quer este ou o outro?

Comment: Quando o aplicativo não abre, apresenta algum erro no LogCat ? Informe também por gentileza.

Comment: Não, apenas diz que a aplicação deixou de funcionar ...

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso ocorra por que você está utilizando `AppComatActivity` que não é compatível com `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` tente isso:

**No style.xml**:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoTitle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

E no seu manifest deixe assim:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitle">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[Link que pode ajudar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat).

Comment: Já consegui resolver! Obrigado